# Interdependent Setter controls in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

Documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html) shows a nice example of interdependent Slider controls in Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[If[m > n, m = n];
 Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}], {n, 1, 
  10, 1}, {m, 1, n, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, I'd like the controls to be setters instead of Sliders.  The first one goes without a hitch:

```
Manipulate[If[m > n, m = n];
 Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}], {n, 1, 
  10, 1, Setter}, {m, 1, n, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the second one kills the expression, and the error-message tooltip is empty (no message in the gray box when I float over the pink death box)

```
Manipulate[If[m > n, m = n];
 Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}], {n, 1, 
  10, 1, Setter}, {m, 1, n, 1, Setter}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can work around by nesting the Manipulates, but this is super ugly:

```
Manipulate[
 Manipulate[If[m > n, m = n];
  Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}], {m, 1, 
   n, 1, Setter}], {n, 1, 10, 1, Setter}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT**:

Reversing the orders of the Setters, as hinted by the workaround, does not help:

```
Manipulate[If[m > n, m = n];
 Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}], {m, 1, n,
   1, Setter}, {n, 1, 10, 1, Setter}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a known limitation (feature)?  Documented somewhere?  Bug?  Or pilot error (i.e., I misunderstand)?  Is there a better way than my workaround to get the effect I want?

Comment: The error message that should be in the empty box is `Range specification in Range[1,n$$,1] does not have appropriate bounds. >>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
Manipulate[If[m > n, m = n];
 Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}], 
 {n, 1, 10, 1, Setter}, {{m, 1}, Range[1, n, 1], SetterBar}]
```

[image: Out]

To me it seems to be just a limitation to what kind of input syntax `Manipulate` is able to interpret correctly.  Your `{m, 1, n, 1, Setter}` is correctly transformed into a `SetterBar` with a `Range`, but due to the interconnection `n` is wrapped into `Dynamic`, which causes `Range` to produce the error.

Your input results in something similar to

```
{SetterBar[Dynamic[a], Range[5]], Range[1, Dynamic[a], 1]}
```

or

```
{SetterBar[Dynamic[a], Range[5]], Dynamic@Range[1, Dynamic[a], 1]}
```

which both produces an error, as the correct input syntax would be

```
{SetterBar[Dynamic[a], Range[5]], Dynamic@Range[1, a, 1]}
```

The `InputForm` of your input

```
Manipulate[If[m > n, m = n];
  Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}], {n, 1, 
   10, 1, Setter}, {m, 1, n, 1, Setter}] // InputForm
```

reveals that `Dynamic[n]` is used, whereas the `InputForm` of my code

```
Manipulate[If[m > n, m = n];
  Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}], {n, 1, 
   10, 1, Setter}, {{m, 1}, Range[1, n, 1], SetterBar}] // InputForm
```

shows that `Dynamic[Range[1, n, 1]]` is used instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is an aside. You might want to use

```
Row[{{{m}, {n}} // MatrixForm, " = ", Binomial[n, m]}]
```

It displays better. For example,

```
With[{m = 2, n = 6}, Row[{{{m}, {n}} // MatrixForm, " = ", Binomial[n, m]}]]
```

[image: binomial]