# Interdependent SetterBars with symbolic contents

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

In [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88553/interdependent-setter-controls-in-manipulate), I learned how to cascade or nest interdependent `Setter` and `SetterBar` controls with numerical Ranges. The puzzle has arisen again, this time with lists containing symbols. This puzzle is not, to me, in any obvious way a duplicate of the prior one.

Consider this miniature database of destination cities:

```
destinations = {SLC, DEN, OKC, MSY, ABQ};
```

and this function (as a lookup table) from destination city to pair of nearby source cities:

```
src[SLC] = {ONT, PHX}; 
src[DEN] = {PHX, DFW}; 
src[OKC] = {DFW, SAT}; 
src[MSY] = {DFW, TPA}; 
src[ABQ] = {DFW, PHX};
```

My first attempt at nested controls, allowing one to choose a destination city and then choose one of the nearby source cities, produced a surprise:

```
Manipulate[
 {dest, source},
 {dest, destinations, SetterBar},
 {{source, src[dest][[1]]}, src[dest], SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Notice that, while the pair of sources for each destination are correctly pulled from the `src` function, there is no default selected item in the lower SetterBar even though I explicitly set it to the first item `src[dest][[1]]`. The default `source` seems always to be (inexplicably) the first city in `destinations` list. The `source` SetterBar works correctly when I click in it, but its default is never set correctly.

I can work around the problem by mapping through indices:

```
Manipulate[
 {dest, src[dest][[source]]},
 {dest, destinations, SetterBar},
 {{source, 1}, {1 -> src[dest][[1]], 2 -> src[dest][[2]]}, SetterBar}]
```

[image]

but this is not a robust solution because it requires me to hardcode the list of button labels in a set of rules. What if I wanted three sources for one of the destinations?

Comment: Maybe, `MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, src[dest]]` in place of `{1 -> src[dest][[1]], 2 -> src[dest][[2]]}` to cover cases where `src[_]` can be of any length?

Comment: This is less about the GUI and more about the code, but: have you considered making `src` an `Association[]`?

Comment: @klgr that works nicely, with "SetterBar" remaining as the control type (the control type defaults to a slider, which is weird because the domain is discrete, but was explained in the referenced older question as a side effect of an implicit `Dynamic`).

Comment: @J.M. I tried associations. With the original control spec, namely `{{source, src[dest][[1]]}, src[dest], SetterBar}`, associations produce the same undesirable results as my first proposal. I have long hypothesized that associations are just an alternative syntax for the traditional, single-bracket, pseudo-functional, pattern-matching notation like `src[dest]`, which produces an internal lookup table (almost certainly a hash table). Semantically, I don't know of a difference between an association and the equivalent set of single-bracket definitions like my original definition of `src`.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin You might want to have a look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations) regarding the use of associations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option `TrackingFunction`

```
destinations = {SLC, DEN, OKC, MSY, ABQ};
src[SLC] = {ONT, PHX}; 
src[DEN] = {PHX, DFW}; 
src[OKC] = {DFW, SAT}; 
src[MSY] = {DFW, TPA}; 
src[ABQ] = {DFW, PHX};
Manipulate[
 {dest, source},
 {dest, destinations, SetterBar,TrackingFunction->(dest=#;source=src[dest][[1]];&)},
 {source, src[dest], SetterBar}]
```

**EDIT**

Here is a new version with the right initialisation :

```
destinations = {SLC, DEN, OKC, MSY, ABQ};
src[SLC] = {ONT, PHX}; 
src[DEN] = {PHX, DFW}; 
src[OKC] = {DFW, SAT}; 
src[MSY] = {DFW, TPA}; 
src[ABQ] = {DFW, PHX};
Manipulate[
 {dest, source},
 {dest, destinations, SetterBar,TrackingFunction->(dest=#;source=src[#][[1]];&)},
 {source, src[dest], SetterBar},
 Initialization:> (dest=destinations[[1]];source = src[destinations[[1]]][[1]])]
```

Comment: This is *the* option I *always* forget the name and it's impossible to find the name by consulting the documentation.

Comment: This is close to best because I can use `source` directly and not `src[dest][[source]]` in the content of the Manipulate. If you fix a couple of things, I'll mark it as the answer. I had to change the TrackingFunction to `TrackingFunction -> (dest = #; source = src[#][[1]]; &` and the initial value of `source` to `src[destinations[[1]]][[1]]`.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is the following:

```
Manipulate[{dest, source},
 {dest, destinations, SetterBar},
 {source, (source = src[dest][[1]]; SetterBar[Dynamic[source], src[dest]]) &}
]
```

This works by manually specifying the control for `source`. The function that generates the control simply sets `source` explicitly to the desired default value.

Comment: This is also a great answer because I can use `source` instead of `src[dest][[source]]` in the content of the Manipulate. I prefer andre's `TrackingFunction` solution because of (subjectively) more obvious semantics. In other words, if I had known about `TrackingFunction` I probably would have thought of andre's solution before yours, but that's only because I would have been distracting by thinking `source` is already `Dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[{dest, src[dest][[source]]}, 
 {dest, destinations, SetterBar}, 
 {{source, 1}, MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, src[dest]], SetterBar}]
```

[image]